# Checking if node exist in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I know there are many questions about this already but I couldnt find out how can I check this, people generally check if the attribute exist or does that tag have a value. I need to check if the tag exists
Here is my XML file

```
<a>
<b has attributes/>
<c>
<d/>
<e/>
</c>
</a>
```

Now I need to check if the B element exists. I dont need any of its attributes or values or anything, just need to check if its there or not. And there can be more b's inside c tags. is there any way to check the b only under the a instead of checking in whole XML file?

Comment: There are like 4 apis (probably many more) for XML handling in .NET... which one you are using? `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, ...

Comment: I use 2 type of apis to handle, if this xml file does not exist I use XmlWriter if the file already exist I use xelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(doc.SelectSingleNode("/a/b")!=null)
```

Comment: if(doc.SelectSingleNode("a")!=null) I used it this way and it worked Thank you

Comment: But you missed out on the "/"

Comment: @bommelding there is a word instead of a character and I did use it without / and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/a/b"); 

if(node !=null){
...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 try
            {
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/test.xml");

                var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("a");
                if (node != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("a Exist");
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("a Not Found");
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
```

I've used this as solution and it worked. Thanks for the replies,I'll use this as answer but still this code check whole XML so if a node named "a" exist inside node c as example it still says a exist.

Comment: Now it is about "a" instead of "b" ??  And XmlDoc instead of XDoc?